# Can't delete/add or see any entries in one Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

I use Google Calendar on a regular basis, and somehow one single Calendar I created is now empty.

I can't add entries to this calendar.

The settings also seem very different from the settings of other calendars:
[image]

I also can't delete the calendar (the option is just missing):[image]

I recently shared the .ics link to this calendar with a coworker. Could this have anything to do with the missing entries?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Have you asked for help on [Google's forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar?hl=en&utm_source=HC&utm_medium=leftnav&utm_campaign=calendar)?

Comment: Not yet, thanks for the link - I'll maybe try that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has resolved itself. The calendar is now back and working normally.